# Your connection is not private when using chrome 80 and chromedriver v80

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, certificate, selenium-chromedriver

I was using chrome 79, everything was fine... But after updating to chrome version 80 my Selenium script is just ignoring my capabilities arguments, I was using only the following argument (args) for security capabilities, and it was fine `"--ignore-certificate-errors"`.

I couldn't find anything on internet, already tried to use other args such as `"--disable-web-security"` , also tried to run the script on my local machine (localhost) with the following arg  `"--allow-insecure-localhost"` and it still does not work...

Please let me know if there's something I'm missing, many thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgraded Chrome to version 80, then upgrade Chromedriver as well.
Get chromedriver version 80 [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=80.0.3987.16/)

The generic rule is your Chrome and Chromedriver versions must be aligned - *"ChromeDriver uses the same version number scheme as Chrome."*, as documented [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection), along with steps for choosing the correct Chromedriver version.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that, but sure, this was my first action... Chromedriver is already up to date

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and first i tried using desired capabilities Accept_SSL_ Certs ,but it didn't work so I handled it by using below code

Page class-> private connection page locator and code

```
@FindBy(css = "body#body.ssl")
private WebElement ssl_Body;

@FindBy(xpath = "//button[@id='details-button']")
private WebElement btn_Advance;

@FindBy(xpath = "//a[@id='proceed-link']")
private WebElement btn_Proceed;
```

public void handlePrivateConnecion()
 {

```
    if(isElementPresent(ssl_Body)){
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(btn_Advance)).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(btn_Proceed)).click();
        logger.info("Private connection handled.");
    }else {
        logger.info("Private connection page not displayed.");
    }
}

private Boolean isElementPresent(WebElement element) {

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    try {
        element.isDisplayed();
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUtils.WAIT_FOR_ELEMENT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently found the same, and the only way I could resolve the issue was to set the `acceptInsecureCerts` flag. Now seems to work fine.